# How to retrieve a parameter from Array (Google Analytics table with hits in BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get new table with EventInfo from my GA view such as EventAction, EventCategory and EventLabel. But I face the following problem
Cannot access field eventInfo on a value with type `ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [2:6]`

Even after trying to compose query as mentioned above, I am getting an error.
    ARRAY>

Could you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: What error are you getting? And can you show us the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visitId, visitNumber, hit.eventInfo.*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
UNNEST(hits) hit
WHERE NOT eventInfo IS NULL
```

with result as something like below

```
visitId     visitNumber eventCategory       eventAction     eventLabel                      eventValue   
1501607501  1           Enhanced Ecommerce  Quickview Click YouTube Men's Vintage Henley    null     
1501633019  1           Enhanced Ecommerce  Quickview Click YouTube Custom Decals           null
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!